# asp.net mvc saving and displaying images in db

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how do you go about saving images and displaying them from a SQL Server Image field when using ASP.NET MVC?

Many thanks
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MvcFutures http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18459 project has a FileResult which is a type of ActionResult. You could probably use that to return a binary stream to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this pretty simply yourself with a controller action:

```
public void RenderImage(int imageId)
{
    // TODO: Replace this with your API to get the image blob data.
    byte[] data = this.repo.GetImageData(imageId);

    if (data != null)
    {
        // This assumes you're storing JPEG data
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Expires = 0;
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    }
    else
    {
        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```